# Конвертация массива байтов в массив short и обратно

Tags: java, массивы

```
public void createAndPlayAudioTrack(View view) {
    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            SAMPLE_RATE_8000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            bufferSize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    startWriteAndPlayProcess();
}

public void startWriteAndPlayProcess() {
    writeAudio();
    playAudio();
}

private void writeAudio() {
    audioTrack.write(audioBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
}

private void playAudio() {
    audioTrack.play();
}
```

Код сверху достает из аудиобуфера данные (`audiobuffer` - это байтовый массив с аудиоданными). Мне надо эти данные конвертировать в массив `long`, потом развернуть массив задом наперед, потом вернуть в байтовый массив и подставить в метод `writeAudio()`. Но сделать это не получается.

Comment: Вы бы хоть язык и платформу указали. Java?

Comment: Простите, сейчас

Comment: @ВіталійШимко: Для этого обычно используют метки.

Comment: я новенький здесь, еще не очень разобрался. Помогите с заданием

Comment: Окей, а для чего конвертировать в long? Лучше объясните, что должно быть с байтами и их порядком. Может, быть, данные лежат в BigEndian, а вам нужно LittleEndian, или что-то наподобие?

Comment: Сначала я просто пробовал развернуть массив с байтами, но это не давало результата, тогда я начал спрашивать почему. Мне 1 человек ответил что данные теряются, поэтому их надо сначала перевести в массив с лонг, например.

Comment: Простите я не силен в понятиях BigEndian и LittleEndian. Но в принципе да, похоже что именно так.

Comment: Вы может лучше приведите пример, что должно случиться с байтами? Например, исходный массив: #0 #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7 -> результат? Потому что пока не вполне понятно.

Comment: я допустил ошибку: имел ввиду byte -> short. в общем. раз 1 байт это половина шорта, значит 1 шорт - это 2 байта. получается что массив должен стать в 2 раза короче, но обьем данных не измениться. Я не знаю как вам еще обьяснить.

Comment: Вы всё же напишите, что должно реально произойти с байтами. Конвертация в short, переворот и обратная конвертация выглядят _очень_ подозрительно.

Comment: я понимаю что подозрительно, но это именно так и должно случиться. иначе никак. разворот массива байтов дает шум в микрофоне

Answer (score 1):

Ну, давайте попробуем развернуть на месте.

```
int n = audiobuffer.length;
if (n % 2 != 0)
    throw new ...

for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i += 2)
{
    //    i      i+1    ...... (n-i-2) (n-i-1) -->
    // (n-i-2) (n-i-1)  ......    i      i+1
    byte tmp = audiobuffer[i];
    audiobuffer[i] = audiobuffer[n-i-2];
    audiobuffer[n-i-2] = tmp;

    tmp = audiobuffer[i+1];
    audiobuffer[i+1] = audiobuffer[n-i-1];
    audiobuffer[n-i-1] = tmp;
}
```

Это конечно если я правильно понял ваш вопрос.