# преобразовать byte массив в long массив и обратно

Tags: java, массивы

Есть массив данных, заполненный аудиоданными с помощью класса Audiorecord. Мне надо это проиграть задом наперед. Чтобы это сделать, данные надо конвертировать в long,  развернуть (дабы избежать потери данных) и вернуть в байт массив.

Comment: Вопрос весьма похож на этот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430365

Comment: Не делайте дублирующих вопросов.

Comment: Что-то мне не кажется, что если тупо развернуть байты, проиграется задом наперёд. Вы ж не ожидаете, что если вы переставите байты в JPEG-картинке, она перевернётся вверх ногами?

Answer (score 1):

Причем тут проигрывание задом наперед?

1) Или вы хотите проиграть задом наперед

2) или вы хотите сконвертить массив байтов в `long` и обратно.

Не имею ни малейшего понятия как ответить на первый вопрос, а на второй знаю - следите за руками:

```
//конвертация массива байтов в одиночный long
public static long byteArrayToLong(byte[] buffer, int offset) {
        return (buffer[offset] << 56)
                + ((buffer[offset+1] & 0xFF) << 48)
                + ((buffer[offset+2] & 0xFF) << 40)
                + ((buffer[offset+3] & 0xFF) << 32)
                + ((buffer[offset+4] & 0xFF) << 24)
                + ((buffer[offset+5] & 0xFF) << 16)
                + ((buffer[offset+6] & 0xFF) << 8)
                + (buffer[offset+7] & 0xFF);
    }

//конвертация одиночного long'а в массив byte
public static byte[] longToByteArray(long value) {
    return new byte[]
            {
            (byte)(value >>> 56),
            (byte)(value >>> 48),
            (byte)(value >>> 40),
            (byte)(value >>> 32),
            (byte)(value >>> 24),
            (byte)(value >>> 16),
            (byte)(value >>> 8),
            (byte)value
            };

}
```